# Wordpress.org blog - centering a featured image at the top of a post

Tags: css, image, wordpress, center, wordpress-featured-image

I use wordpress.org and bluehost for my site: www.thekatsup.com

The home page is a bunch of album covers and then you click an album and it opens up to the post with the song's cover image, an audio link, and a download link.

The image is set through the "featured image" option so I can't change it in the post via HTML, it must be done through CSS.

From toying with it I've found that toying with [this](http://postimage.org/image/hhl5g1hwf/) (screen shot) part of the CSS moves around the album cover, but then it also moves my other images in the post.

Is there a way to center the album cover for all my albums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
display: block;
```

will do the trick

Your rule:

```
.post img {
background:#fff;
border:0 solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
padding:3px;
display: block;
margin:0 auto;
margin-bottom:15px;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This has been driving me nuts for like 2 weeks, best day ever... Thank you!